# How do I figure out the path to CDN?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, cdn, applicationcustomizers

I am following this article to deploy add a script editor extension:

https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4

I've activated my CDN and I can build using **--ship** and deploy web parts or extensions to my SharePoint Online **App Catalog** and add them successfully in my pages.

The only problem is: **I don't know the path to my CDN is**.

I know I have enabled Office 365 public CDN and that I am using it but I don't know how to fill this:

***"cdnBasePath": "-- PATH TO CDN --"***

in the step 2 of the aforementioned article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN path can be configured in three ways :

1. Azure CDN
2. Office 365 Public CDN
3. SharePoint Library in your tenant

**How to configure the CDN in Office 365?**

Follow the below steps:

- Download and install the latest version of SharePoint Online
  Management Shell from
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588
- Open the SharePoint Online Management Shell
- Connect to SharePoint Online tenant using below cmdlet

  Connect-SPOService -Url https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com
- Run below set of commands to review the existing Office 365 Public CDN settings on your tenant

  Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Public

**How to Update CDN Path in the SPFx project file?**

- Open **write-manifests.json** from config folder
- Update CDN base path as Office 365 CDN end point
         `https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/[tenant]/sites/[site-collection-name]/[document-library]/[folder]`

Using the below command **Prepare the package**

```
gulp bundle --ship
```

Using the below command **Deploy Package to SharePoint**

```
gulp package-solution --ship
```

For details refer to the below article :

[SharePoint Framework - Deploy SPFx WebParts To Office 365 Public CDN](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-deploy-spfx-webparts-to-office-365-public-cdn/)

Answer (score 1):

Path of CDN you have to pick, basically it is the location where all you files stored.
it can be anywhere inside your site collection, as in your reference blogs, **he created a new folder "CDN" inside the Site assets library.**

You can do the same, go to your site collection > site content > Site assets > Now create a Folder "CDN" no use that path. it will be like this `"https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitecollectionname/siteassets/CDN`"

[image]